# Sparse matrix multiplication in MATLAB with spfun

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, elementwise-operations

I have a dense column matrix `y` of size `(m,1)` and a sparse matrix `x` of size `(m,n)`.
I want to do element-wise multiplication using `y` and every column of `x`.
The resultant sparse matrix is still of size `(m,n)`.
Sparse matrix `x`, when loaded into memory, is about 10GB.
Can `spfun` help me accomplish my goal in a memory efficient manner?

I am having difficulties understanding the logic behind it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun)?

```
out = bsxfun( @times, x, y );
```

---

[`spfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html) is more suitable for element-wise operations where you manipulate each non-zero element of `x`. It is not exactly fit for matrix-vector element wise operations.
However, if you want to do something along this line, you might try:

```
[ii jj xij] = find(x); %// extract non-zeros of x and their locations
out = sparse( ii, jj, xij.*y(ii), size(x,1), size(x,2) );
```

See [`doc find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budqvni-1) for more information.

Comment: Cool, I never knew multiplying a normal matrix with a sparse matrix was possible and that it results in a sparse as well

Comment: Actually, I wasn't aware that bsxfun is applicable to sparse matrices... .

Comment: @yi416 `bsxfun` rocks!!