# Scale every row in a sparse matrix by an element of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix

```
obj.resOp = sparse(row,col,val);
```

and a vector containing the sums of each row in the matrix

```
sums = sparse(sum(obj.resOp,2));
```

Now what I want to do is

```
obj.resOp = obj.resOp ./ sums;
```

which would scale every row in the matrix so that the rowsum in each row is 1.

However in this last line, MATLAB internally seems to construct a full matrix from `obj.resOp` and hence I get this error:

> Error using ./ Requested 38849x231827 (17.5GB) array exceeds maximum
>   array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may
>   take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference
>   panel for more information.

for sufficiently large matrices.

In theory I think that expanding to a full matrix is not necessary. Is there any MATLAB formulation of what I want to achieve while keeping the sparsity of `obj.resOp`?

Comment: It's likely relevant to know which version of MATLAB you're using?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB 2017a.

Comment: obj.resOp = inv(diag(sums)) * obj.resOp;  should give me the same result, but is killed. That could be a bug in my vectors though.

Comment: Some of the entries in `sum` were zero which is why the above didn't work. After fixing this, everything works fine! 
Anyway, thank you for your suggestion, @Wolfie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a method similar to the one [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627923/3978545).

Start with some sparse matrix

```
% Random sparse matrix: 10 rows, 4 cols, density 20%
S = sprand(10,4, 0.2);
```

Get the row sums, note that `sum` returns a sparse matrix from sparse inputs, so no need for your additional conversion ([docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html)).

```
rowsums = sum(S,2);
```

Find all non-zero indices and their values

```
[rowidx, colidx, vals] = find(S)
```

Now create a sparse matrix from the element-wise division

```
out = sparse(rowidx, colidx, vals./rowsums(rowidx), size(S,1), size(S,2));
```

Comment: This solution is indeed faster than mine and is less prone to running out of memory.

Comment: Glad I could help, the method was new to me too so good to know it works well

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent calculation

```
obj.resOp = inv(diag(sums)) * obj.resOp;
```

works smoothly.

Comment: Avoid using `inv` at all costs unless absolutely necessary.  It is known to be error-prone.  Because you are finding the inverse of a diagonal matrix, the result is simply another diagonal matrix whose coefficients are the inverse.  Therefore: `inv(diag(sums)) --> diag(1./sums)`.  This article by [John D. Cook should prove to be enlightening](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Implemented.